# Lowercase a field in namedtuple in python

Tags: python, namedtuple

I have this `namedtuple` with redefined `__str__()`

```
class MyTuple(namedtuple('MyTuple', 'field1 field2')):
    __slots__ = ()                                                                                                    
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}:{}'.format(self.field1, self.field2)
```

Every time I create an instance I also would like to lowercase the value of the first field so I could get:

```
>>>s = MyTuple('FOO','BAR')
>>>print s
foo:BAR
```

instead of

```
FOO:BAR
```

Modifying it in `__str__()` is not a solution in my case.

Comment: You mean you want the *value stored* to be lowercased?

Comment: Yes. This is what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `__new__` static method and apply the lowercasing there:

```
class MyTuple(namedtuple('MyTuple', 'field1 field2')):
    __slots__ = ()                                                                                                    

    def __new__(cls, field1, field2):
        """Create a new instance of MyTuple(field1, field2)"""
        return super(MyTuple, cls).__new__(cls, field1.lower(), field2)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}:{}'.format(self.field1, self.field2)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> class MyTuple(namedtuple('MyTuple', 'field1 field2')):
...     __slots__ = ()                                                                                                    
...     def __new__(cls, field1, field2):
...         """Create a new instance of MyTuple(field1, field2)"""
...         return super(MyTuple, cls).__new__(cls, field1.lower(), field2)
...     def __str__(self):
...         return '{}:{}'.format(self.field1, self.field2)
... 
>>> mt = MyTuple('FOO', 'BAR')
>>> mt
MyTuple(field1='foo', field2='BAR')
>>> print(mt)
foo:BAR
>>> mt.field1
'foo'
>>> mt.field2
'BAR'
```